# How to print the specific <div> content in new window using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html code which i used javascript.(If it is possible with jquery suggest me)

```js
<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
    myWindow.document.write(#tobePrint);
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="tobePrint">Print the content of this div content in new window.</div>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The new window that I am trying is coming in new tab,i need the new window to come across the side of the tab.The content that is inside the **div** should be displayed in that new window.So i tried to  **myWindow.document.write(#tobePrint);** access Id and tried to print but it is not working.

Comment: You can't control where new windows are opened. It's down to the user's settings in their browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Working solution:

```js
var myWindow;

function openWin() {

    myWindow = window.open("myWindow","newwin") 
    var tobePrint = $('#tobePrint').text();
    myWindow.document.write('<p>' + tobePrint+ '</p>');
    
}

function closeWin() {
    myWindow.close();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="tobePrint">Print the content of this div content in new window.</div>

<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
</body>
```

Comment: shows me error like "Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Answer (score 0):

you can get div content from like code on the bottom line at opened window

```
 window.opener.document.getElementById('tobePrint').innerHTML
```

Comment: can u please elaborate me?

Comment: I wrote another answer

Answer (score 0):

get content of  your "tobePrint" div from your child window. Write this code on your child window.

```
$(document).ready
(
   function () 
  {
      alert(window.parent.document.getElementById('tobePrint').innerHTML);
              }

  );
```